# Python: Read data from Highcharts after setExtreme

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, highcharts

I'm trying to get the data from a Highcharts chart using Selenium. My issue  is that the `setExtremes` function does not work with `.options.data`. How can I read data after using `setExtremes` using purely Python-based methods?

My code:

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities, executable_path=gecko_binary_path)
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(5)

temp = driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[0].series[0]'
                             '.xAxis[0].setExtremes(Date.UTC(2017, 0, 7), Date.UTC(2017, 0, 8))'
                             '.options.data'
                            )

data = [item for item in temp]
print(data)
```

Comment: Does this JS work in the browser using the dev console?

Comment: Relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: @JeffC no it doesn't. t may be that the order of operations is off i.e. `setExtremes` must be called during the series but I've exhausted all efforts on my end.

Comment: Then you need to simplify what you are attempting. There's no need to involve python and Selenium if the basic JS in the console isn't working. Part of writing an [mcve] is narrowing down the problem to only the issue. Please rewrite your question to focus on the JS command and getting that working. Once that is working, my guess is that putting that JS code into Selenium will work just fine.

Comment: Can you split your code into two separate executions? Something like this: `window.Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(Date.UTC(2017, 0, 7)` to set extremes, then `return window.Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].options.data`.

Comment: @PawełFus splitting this out does not work as the commands aren't in the same session

Comment: You can combine two statement with semicolon in a single execute script as follows temp = driver.execute_script(' window.Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(Date.UTC(20‌​17, 0, 7),Date.UTC(2017, 0, 8));return return window.Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].options.data')

Comment: It depends on how the change of bound is handled. If the data are already cached then use two statements as @Murthi suggested. If not, the chart will probably have to request the server to get the data which mean that you'll have to wait for the data to be refreshed with `execute_sync_script`. Note that you can get the cached data via `Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.series[0].data`.

Comment: @FlorentB.are you willing to add a solution for this. Currently the best answer is native to Javascript.

Comment: Also `execute_sync_script` doesn't exist in the `driver` as a method

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to execute your code on Highcharts [demo page](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic)
The problem is with `xAxis[0]`, `xAxis` is not an array but a dictionary, so you must supply a string value there inside those `[]`.

check `xAxis` in [the docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis) 
I am guessing you're looking for [`xAxis.events.setExtremes`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.setExtremes)

#### Edit

I see now that xAxis can be an array, but you're most likely missing those `events` so my solution should be changed to `xAxis[0].events.setExtremes`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `setExtremes(min, max)` method returns `undefined`, so you can not chain options. Solution is to wrap this method and pass on context, for example:

```js
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'setExtremes', function (proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return this; // <-- context for chaining
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

Now we can use:

```
return window.Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max).series[0].options.data;
```

Note: The snippet can be placed in a separate file and used like any other Highcharts plugin (simply load after Highcharts library).

**Important**

Axis object has references only to series that are bound to this axis. If you want to access any series on the chart use:

```
return window.Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max).chart.series[0].options.data;
```

Comment: I'll be calling this from Python. Is there a way to execute this via Python

Comment: This is how the library works, so you can't fix this in Python unless you use different approach. `setExtremes()` returns `undefined` so you can not chain the properties.. In other words you have two solutions: split your script execution or add a plugin. Just to be on the same page: my snippet can be placed in a file and loaded as any other Highcharts plugin.